# How do copy formulas that contain defined names and unlock the cell refrence in excel 2016?

Tags: excel

If I have a formula

```
=sumif(dates,A1,column_1)  
=sumif(dates,A1,column_2)  
-----------------------------
=sumif(dates,A1,column_30)
```

Normally if the ranges were not defined then I would be able to change column_# into something like

```
=sumif(dates,A1,C$1:C$10)
```

where `C` is not locked, so when copying horizontally it would change the columns referenced automatically.

How would I do the same with defined names?

Edit: I've tried to reference a cell that contains the name of the defined range.

```
=sumif(dates,A2,C1)
```

where `C1` contains

```
column_1
```

but that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach with using a cell reference that contains the range name will work, but you need to wrap the cell in Indirect().

```
=sumif(dates,A2,Indirect(C1))
```